# How can I get each length of x, y, z, and degree of p?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm receiving gyroscope data (`g1`, `g2`, `g3`) in degree.

Also I know the length of radius `r`.

I wanna get each length of `x`, `y`, `z`, and the degree of `p` from the gyroscope data.
Please refer the attached this image.

Please help me how I can get them.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misinterpreted all the implied Right Angles of your diagram (I know nothing about gyros), it seems to me that

AC = y / Sin(g1)

AE = y / Tan(g3)   then

Tan(p) = Sin(g1)/Tan(g3)   This therefore solves for p  (= Inverse-Tan(Sin(g1)/Tan(g3))

(so p is unaffected by g2)

with p solved you can then extract the line lengths

x = EA = r.Sin(p)

z = x . Tan(g2)

y = z. Tan(g1)

hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response.

 `z = EF = r * Sin(P)`

I think it's incorrect. 
Please check above image, again.

Comment: My perspective was wrong, I thought we were looking at triangle CFE. You are correct